# Is there a way to test my program on other platforms without installing a VM?

Tags: python, testing, cross-platform

I am writing a python program and I want to test it on other platforms - windows 7, 8, XP, vista and also 32 bit and 64 bit. Is there a way to do that without installing a VM for each platform?

VM installation takes a lot of time and space and it just seems like an overkill for simply testing a program.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's too broad because there are too many possible answers, can you very very shortly point me to some of theme? I really have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an account in a cloud service like [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), [HP](http://www.hpcloud.com/) or [Microsoft](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/). Open few machines with different operating systems, easy and simple!

most of them will even provide free trial or micro server for free

more then enough to test your program

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about those services! I know I'm really asking for a lot, but is there a way not to give a phone number nor a credit card? (And not paypal and so on)

Comment: @EllaShar you could finds lots of free no credit card or phone required, like https://trial.host1plus.com/register.php. But usually they wont supply you with a big variety of servers, just search for them in google.    

ps. if my answer helped you, consider accepting it

Comment: They require a phone number and want to verify it :\

Comment: @EllaShar u can try service like this: http://receivesmsonline.com/

Comment: It does not approve any of the free phone numbers there